# RxJava: observeOn, subscribeOn, and doFinally, switching between IO and UI thread

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I am running into an issue where my observable is subscribed on an IO thread and observed on the android main (UI) thread but the `doFinally` operator is run on the IO thread and it needs to be run on the UI thread.

The usecase is almost exactly the same as this [medium article](https://medium.com/@ValCanBuild/making-rxjava-code-tidier-with-doonsubscribe-and-dofinally-3748f223d32d).

I essentially want to show a `ProgressBar` when the Observable is subscribed to and hide the `ProgressBar` when the Observable is terminated or finished.

The error I am getting is: **java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper!**

Can anyone help me move the `doFinally` action back to the UI thread which has a looper?  Or am I missing some other piece of information?

**EDIT**
The usecase workflow is:

-> Launch Activity

-> initialize

-> execute observable stream

-> Start new Activity and finish current activity

-> New activity

-> Start original activity and finish

-> repeat initialize

Thank you very much.

Details:

- RxJava 2.0.7
- RxAndroid 2.0.1
- Android sdk min 14 and target 25

Example Code

```
listUseCase.execute(null)
            .doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
                    getView().showLoading(true);
                }
            })
            .doFinally(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    getView().showLoading(false);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.main())
            .subscribe(
                    new Consumer<List<AccountEntity>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@NonNull List<AccountEntity> accountEntities) throws Exception {
                            getView().setAccounts(accountEntities);
                        }
                    },
                    new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            if (isViewAttached()) {
                                getView().showError(throwable.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
```

Stack Trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
  Process: com.example.android.demo.customerfirst.alpha, PID: 16685
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread must have a looper!
      at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue(Choreographer.java:96)
      at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue(Choreographer.java:91)
      at java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values.getAfterMiss(ThreadLocal.java:430)
      at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:65)
      at android.view.Choreographer.getInstance(Choreographer.java:192)
      at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.<init>(ValueAnimator.java:600)
      at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.<init>(ValueAnimator.java:575)
      at android.animation.ValueAnimator.getOrCreateAnimationHandler(ValueAnimator.java:1366)
      at android.animation.ValueAnimator.end(ValueAnimator.java:998)
      at android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable.stop(AnimatedVectorDrawable.java:439)
      at android.widget.ProgressBar.stopAnimation(ProgressBar.java:1523)
      at android.widget.ProgressBar.onVisibilityChanged(ProgressBar.java:1583)
      at android.view.View.dispatchVisibilityChanged(View.java:8643)
      at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9686)
      at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:6663)
      at android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.java:1563)
      at com.example.android.demo.customerfirst.featuresstore.list.ProductListActivity.showLoading(ProductListActivity.java:121)
      at com.example.android.demo.customerfirst.featuresstore.list.ProductListPresenterMediator$3.run(ProductListPresenterMediator.java:56)
      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoFinally$DoFinallyObserver.runFinally(ObservableDoFinally.java:144)
      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoFinally$DoFinallyObserver.onComplete(ObservableDoFinally.java:94)
      at io.reactivex.internal.observers.DisposableLambdaObserver.onComplete(DisposableLambdaObserver.java:73)
      at io.reactivex.internal.observers.DeferredScalarDisposable.complete(DeferredScalarDisposable.java:84)
      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromCallable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromCallable.java:52)
      at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10700)
      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnLifecycle.subscribeActual(ObservableDoOnLifecycle.java:33)
      at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10700)
      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoFinally.subscribeActual(ObservableDoFinally.java:45)
      at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10700)
      at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$1.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:39)
      at io.reactivex.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:138)
      at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)
      at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was occurring because I was not disposing the subscription when an activity was finished/destroyed.

Now each activity/view tells the presenter when they are stopped or destroyed and the presenter disposes of the subscription.

This appears to have solved my issue.

```
 @Override
public void initialize() {
    if (!isViewAttached()) {
        throw new ViewNotAttachedException();
    }
    disposable = listUseCase.execute(null)
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io()) // Move subscribe on here
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.main()) // Change threads here
            .doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
                    getView().showLoading(true); // This should be on the main thread also
                }
            })
            .doFinally(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    getView().showLoading(false);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(
                    new Consumer<List<AccountEntity>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@NonNull List<AccountEntity> accountEntities) throws Exception {
                            getView().setAccounts(accountEntities);
                        }
                    },
                    new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            if (isViewAttached()) {
                                getView().showError(throwable.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    if (disposable != null) {
        disposable.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is move the `observeOn` up the chain. The `observeOn` method changes the thread that `onNext`, `onError`, and `onCompleted` are called on which is internally how operations & side effects work (via lift)

```
listUseCase.execute(null)
            .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io()) // Move subscribe on here
            .observeOn(schedulerProvider.main()) // Change threads here
            .doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
                    getView().showLoading(true); // This should be on the main thread also
                }
            })
            .doFinally(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    getView().showLoading(false);
                }
            })

            .subscribe(
                    new Consumer<List<AccountEntity>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@NonNull List<AccountEntity> accountEntities) throws Exception {
                            getView().setAccounts(accountEntities);
                        }
                    },
                    new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            if (isViewAttached()) {
                                getView().showError(throwable.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
```

Comment: The issue still occurs with change.  I will add more information to the original ticket as maybe I am doing something wrong outside of this observable usecase.

Comment: Looks at the error stack trace (or post it) it should tell you where which line is calling on the wrong thread.

Comment: @cryoxis I posted the stack trace.  I feel like the action is coming back on a disposed thread that doesn't have a looper.  I am not doing any disposing actions so I will go and update my activities/views and their presenters to dispose of the observable when they are stopped/paused/destroyed and get back to you.  

Thank you for the insight into the lifting mechanism.  I'll reply with how it goes.

Comment: @JTT You didn't reply. :)

Comment: @milosmns I had posted my own answer with what my problem and fix was.  Is that not the correct thing to do?

Comment: @JTT I didn't see the answer was also yours, oops. Ok, thanks, looking into it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is too late.
But check the documentation [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#doFinally-io.reactivex.functions.Action-) about the `doFinally`
They say explicitly"

> Calls the specified action after this Observable signals `onError` or `onCompleted` or **gets disposed** by the downstream.

That means that `doFinally` it will be called anyway, and it is not warranted that you have a valid context.

I do not use `doFinally` for this things. I set the loading(false) `onNext` or `onError` always. Not pretty but effective.

Comment: Yes. There is no guarantee ``doFinally`` would be called in the thread specified in ``observeOn``. I personally prefer for such cases ``doAfterTerminate`` which is described in the docs as "to be called after this Single invokes either onSuccess or onError" that perfectly fits for me when working with ``LiveData``.